# increment of void* type-casted as char* fails

Tags: c, pointers, void, c89, pointer-arithmetic

In a function like this:

```
char nextchr (void* p)
{
    ((char*)p)++;

    return *(((char*)p));
}
```

That is supposed to return the second character of a string literal passed as the argument *p* simply fails to do that.

Why that could be?

---

### Solution summery:

@M.M :
`++` requires a lvalue (left-handed value) for it to apply to and the result from the type-cast isn't that.

@OP Update :
Some compilers (generally /old C89/ /*compilers*/ like mine) may allow `((char*)source)++;` /as long as it is not passed as argument to a function/ even though it is illegal and proven as illegal by the C standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`++` requires an lvalue. Your code could be:

```
char *c = p;
++c;
return *c;
```

although it would be a lot simpler to write `return ((char *)p)[1];`

Comment: So do I surely need to pass it to a `char*` if I want this to work ? Why the version with the type-casting doesn't work? I know I do it right..

Comment: @Malina sorry I'm not sure what you are asking. My code does implement "return the second character of a string literal passed as the argument p". Your version doesn't work because `++` may only be applied to an lvalue, and the result of a cast is not an lvalue.

Comment: But doesn't explain why mine implementation didn't work. Thanks for the solution though, it just unlocks new questions regarding the same..

Comment: @Malina I have already explained twice why yours didn't work.

Comment: Ahh so the type-casted address isn't lvalue like a regular address provided by say.. the `&` operator.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "regular", but the result of `&` is not an lvalue either. You can't write `++ &x;`

Comment: I surely can do `char nextchr (char* p) { p++; return *p; }` here `p` is a regular address.. how else I could name it

Comment: Yes, `p` is an lvalue. `&x` and `(char *)p` are not lvalues.

Comment: Okay so, this is what i meant. Didn't know if I type cast to `p`, this is not going to return lvalue.

Comment: Moreover it WORKS if done like that: `void* p = "asd";

((char*)p)++;

printf("%c", *((char*)p));` i.e not passed by a function argument. So I guess there is another thing behind this as well..

Comment: What you just posted is illegal code, `((char*)p)++` is ill-formed because `++` may only be applied to lvalues.

Comment: Allright, but then again, why did the same "illegal code" worked when not passed to a function ? It uses exactly the same pointer arithmetic with type-cast and so forth.

Comment: Well, it worked. This is why I asked the question in the first place. It appears to be working only outside a function..... If it doesn't work for you, then it is a very strange, non-standard EiC-specific complication.

Comment: I think some compilers let you write `((char *)p)++` and secretly transform it to `*((char **)&p)++;` . Even if you have such a compiler, it's best not to rely on (or even wonder about) non-standard extensions like that, which don't make much sense anyway.

Comment: It is a very old compiler and as I said, evidently it worked in the illegal form, not passed to a function. So you must be write about the compiler-specific semantic transformation. It is an interpreter behind this after all.

Comment: `*((char **)&p)++;` gives me "Illegal conversion types from char* to char" though. I updated the question with summery.

Comment: @Malina sorry, it should be `(*(char **)&p)++;`  , or `++*(char **)&p;`. Note that this is technically undefined behaviour also (violates something called the *strict aliasing rule*), so only try it for instructional purposes, not in real code. In real code write the simplest-looking code possible that works :)

Comment: Thanks, that was one great suggestion as it has been said from other successful programmers as well.